# Merging fastq files by identifiers with a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have to merge files with the following naming pattern :

```
[SampleID]_[custom_ID01]_ID[RUN_ID]_L001_R1.fastq
[SampleID]_[custom_ID02]_ID[RUN_ID]_L002_R1.fastq
[SampleID]_[custom_ID03]_ID[RUN_ID]_L003_R1.fastq
[SampleID]_[custom_ID04]_ID[RUN_ID]_L004_R1.fastq
```

I need to merge all files with identical [SampleID] but different "Lanes" (L001-L004). 
The following script works fine when directly run in the terminal:

```
custom_id="000"
RUN_ID="0025"
wd="/path/to/script/"  # was missing/ incorrect

 # get ALL sample identifiers
touch temp1.txt
for line in $wd/*.fastq ; do
    fastq_identifier=$(echo "$line" | cut -d"_" -f1);
    echo $fastq_identifier >> temp1.txt
done

# get all uniqe samples identical
cat temp1.txt | uniq > temp2.txt
input_var=$(cat temp2.txt)

# concatenate all fastq (different lanes)  with identical identifier
for line in $input_var; do
        cat $line*fastq >> $line"_"$custom_id"_ID"$Run_ID"_L001_R1.fastq"
done
rm temp1.txt temp2.txt;
```

But if I create a script file (concatenate_fastq.sh) and make it executable

```
 $ chomd +x concatenate_fastq.sh
```

and run it

```
$ ./concatenate_fastq.sh
```

I got the following error:

```
$ concatenate_fastq.sh: line 17: /*.fastq_000_ID_L001_R1.fastq: Keine Berechtigung # = Permission denied
```

Thx to your hints below I solved the problem by fixing

```
wd=/path/to/script/
```

Comment: "Keine Berechtigung" apparently means "Permission denied". Do you use the same user to execute the commands in the shell and to execute the script? Do both runs work on the same directories?

Comment: Nice! And where is line 49?

Comment: My bad. I skipped the commented section in the script. Line 49 is:       cat $line*fastq >> $line"_"$custom_id"_ID"$Run_ID"_L001_R1.fastq"

Comment: Exactly: "keine Berechtigung" means "Permission denied"; The identical user is used to execute the commands and the script. Both runs are executed in the exact same directory (identical path).

Comment: Well in any case your script can't get write access to `$line"_"$custom_id"_ID"$Run_ID"_L001_R1.fastq"`. Either the file already exists but its permissions won't let the script's user write to it, or the file doesn't exists and the directory's permissions won't let the script's user create a new file in it.

Comment: If I directly execute the script Sample01_000_ID0025_L001_R1.fastq (and so forth) are created without any problems. So the user should have the rights to write to the folder. If I run the script I get the error message. Is the script (for whatever reason) trying to write to "/"? As the error is saying: " /*.fastq_000_ID_L001_R1.fastq".

Comment: As an aside, writing intermediate results into statically named temporary files is extremely clunky. In this case, you don't need the temporary files at all, and all of this could be a single pipeline.

Comment: @tripleee: How do I avoid the clunky temporary files? Can you provide a code example?

Comment: `something >file; command <file; rm file` is better written `something | command` and similarly `command > file; cat file; rm file` is better written `command`

Comment: Also `fastq_identifier=$(echo "$line" | cut -d"_" -f1);` is better written `fastq_identifier=${line%%_*}` -- the semicolon at end of line is separately useless.

Comment: Clearly `line` is being expanded to `/*.fastq` which would happen if `wd` was empty and there were no matching files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem seems to be that `wd` is unset.  If you script really genuinely contains exactly the line

```
wd="/path/to/script/"
```

then I would suspect invisible control characters in the script file (using a Windows editor is a common way to shoot yourself in the foot).

More generally, your script should cope correctly when the wildcard does not match any files.  A common way to do that is to `shopt -s nullglob` but the subsequent script would still need adaptation then.

Refactoring the script to loop only over actual matches would help avoid trouble.  Perhaps something like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob  # bashism
printf '%s\n' "$wd"/*.fastq |
cut -d_ -f1 |
uniq |
while read -r line; do
    cat "$line"*fastq >> "${line}_${custom_id}_ID${Run_ID}_L001_R1.fastq"
done
```

You'll notice that this simplifies the script tremendously, and avoids the pesky temporary files.

Comment: in the final script I use  "wd=$1"; I just tried to make a simple working example.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with:

```
if [ $# -ne 3 ] ; then
  echo -e "Usage: $0 {path_to_working_directory} {custom_ID:Z+} {run_ID:ZZZZ}\n"
  exit 1
fi

cwd=$(pwd)
wd=$1
custom_id=$2
RUN_ID=$3
folder=$(basename $wd)

input_var=$(ls *fastq | cut --fields 1 -d "_" | uniq)

for line in $input_var; do
    cat $line*fastq >> $line"_"$custom_id"_ID"$RUN_ID"_L001_R1.fastq"
done
```

Comment: Using a variable for the wildcard matches breaks the script for file names containing whitespace. And you should not use `ls` in scripts. The `printf | cut | uniq | while read` pattern from my answer solves that part.